# Smart Pointer advanced implementation [help, advice, feedback]

Tags: c++, stl, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'd like to get deeper in C++. There are decisions made in STL that I'd like to understand and it's quite hard from just the code.

My idea is to implement some of the STL on my own to understand the pitfalls and so improve my understanding of C++ and improve my code. And I'd like to have some features in STL containers the STD does not have like destruction notification for a resource handling class. I created an extended version of my SharedPointer to contain a std::function as deletion notifier.

And I found some trouble.

Take this code for example: [SmartPointer.hpp](https://pastebin.com/zYHxq6qs)

This is some code I came up with and have some questions.

**Short:**

1. Known problems

   1. Derived classes won't work
   2. Complains about incomplete type
2. Unknown problems

**Long:**

1.1. Derived classes won't work

Just having T as type won't work after the type has been casted. The idea was to pass along OrigT as second parameter so I always know what type ptr points to. I can cast it back and call the correct destructor.

Considering

```
SharedPointer<Derived> member = base.Cast<Derived>();
```

will create T = OrigT and types will not match after cast on assertion I assume. I can't imagine anything how I could solve this.

```
if (!shared->HasReferences())
{
    delete shared;
    
    OriginalValuePointer origPtr = dynamic_cast<OriginalValuePointer>(ptr);
    delete origPtr;
}
```

1.2. Complains about incomplete type

In my examples I get complaints about incomplete type. But I can't figure out why. Currently I am considering making operator* and operator-> templates, too that would be a shot in the dark. I have no clue why it complains and I'd like to ask if you could point me to the problem here.

```
Same code as above in compiler complaint
```

2.2. I think stackoverflow is not the ideal place to ask for feedback but considering my two problems I'd like to ask anyway.

- Does anyone have any sources to **readable** and ideally explained smart pointers? The ones I've found did not quite match my expectations. They were either too simple or did not contain explanation at the critical points.
- I'd appreciate some direct feedback on the code. Afar from coding style of course ;-). Is there anything you directly see where I made a mistake I'll regret? Is there anything that could be done better? (for example, .Cast as member is IMHO a bad choice. For once it is not directly a property of the pointer and I think it might cause flaws I'm not aware of yet.)

I'm really grateful for your help and your opinion.

Stay healthy.

Comment: for some detailed discussion on the design space of smart pointers you could take a look at Modern C++ Design by Alexandrescu. It predates C++11, but nevertheless definitely worth a read

Comment: `ShadedDataPointer` is probably a typo

Comment: Just some nitpicking, but STL is the abbreviation for [the Standard Template Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library), which is kind of a precursor to (but different from) [the C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++_Standard_Library).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I left a similar comment, but after rereading the question, it seems the distinction is already known : *"And I'd like to have some features in STL containers the STD does not have like destruction notification for a resource handling class."*.

Comment: For feedback on existing code, consider posting at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: About base classes, you don't need to know the exact type of a class to delete that. As long as the destructor is virtual calling `delete base` will call the right destructor.

Comment: `I'd appreciate some direct feedback on the code.` if you want to have feedback to the code, you have to include that with your question. Links to externals sites could become invalid anytime, which then might make the question, and answers useless. Besides that  [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might probably be a better place, or probably focus on one part of the problem, like how you could allow the casting, with a reduced part of the code.

Comment: @al3c: `std::shared_ptr` doesn't require a virtual destructor, so presumably OP was trying to emulate that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out codereview.stackexchange.com - I did not know that. Really appreciate the tip.

Comment: @MooingDuck I didn't know that. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

- Normal C++ classes use snake_case, rather than CamelCase.
- This class isn't' thread safe (you probably knew that, but its worth calling out)
- NumReferences returns the count by reference, which isn't useful, and is slightly slower than returning by `int`.
- All methods defined inside the class are automatically `inline`, so you don't need that anywhere.
- `operator ValueType()` is implicit, which is super dangerous. You can make it explicit, but I'd eliminate it entirely.
- `operator ValueType()` needs to know the details of `ValueType` in order to be created. So if `ValueType` isn't fully defined yet, you'll get compiler errors about an incomplete type. Again, deleting the method eliminates this issue.
- `operator SharedPointer<U>()` and `operator bool()` are also implicit. Prefer `explicit`.
- strongly consider adding `assert` to all your methods that use `shared` or `ptr` without checking if it's `null` first.
- `Raw()` is normally named `get()`

---

Now, on to `OrigT` and `Release`: `std::shared_ptr` does an interesting trick where the `SharedData` has inheritance:

```
struct SharedData {
    std::atomic_uint count;
    virtual ~SharedData() {}
};
template<class OrigT>
struct SharedDataImpl {
    OrigT* data;
    ~SharedData() {delete data;}
};
```

Since all the shared_ptrs to the same data will point to the same SharedDataImpl, they don't have to know the most derived class. All they have to do is delete the SharedData member, and it'll automatically clean up the data correctly.  This does require having a second data pointer: one in the `SharedPointer` itself and one in the `SharedData`, but usually this isn't an issue. (Or a `virtual T* get()` method)

Comment: When accessing ptr, or in your case data, would the compiler know how to dereference it without having to dereference twice?

Comment: @Silberling: No. You'd have to either have a second `data` pointer in the `SmartPointer` itself, or accept the performance penalty. I'd recommend the prior, which is why I wrote `SharedData` without a `virtual T* get()` method.

Comment: I commented out
    "operator ValueType() const noexcept" and 
    "template <typename U> operator SharedPointer<U>() const noexcept"
but it still complains because if an incomplete type. std::shared_ptr in the place where I tried my SharedPointer works just fine.

Comment: @Silberling: Which line complains about incomplete types?  I don't see anything else that should require a complete type, at least to instantiate the class itself. What's the full error message, and on which line does it complain? Is it the `Construct` method?